# Connecting Google Compute Engine MongoDB instances

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, google-compute-engine

I'm a systems/architecture noob, and am trying to get an understanding of how to use multiple GCE instances to run a Meteor app.  [This walkthrough](https://github.com/Q42/meteor-gce) seems pretty straightforward for getting Meteor running on a single instance, but if I want to add more instances it isn't clear to me how to connect them together.

From what I understand, I'll add each instance to an [instance group](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/) and use a load-balancer to direct incoming traffic evenly across them.  It also seems like I want to attach a persistent disk to each instance which the OS will boot from and which will include a MongoDB installation that participates in a "replicated set".

Is that accurate?  And if so, how do I actually tell the MongoDB installation on each instance's disk to be a part of the replicated set?

Comment: The steps to add members to mongoDB replica set are mentioned on this link (http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/tutorial/expand-replica-set/). Make sure to select the right mongoDB version from the doc.